# Div elements are not expanding to size of their parent container

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to create a simple webpage using React. I want to have a fixed navbar at the top of the screen and then content below it. My general structure is one in which there is a single div in the body, which is where the React application is "injected". The application itself consists of a top-level "app" div, and various child components.

```
<html>
  <head>
   <title>Sample App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="react">
    </div>
  </body>
  <script src="/build/bundle.js"></script>
</html>
```

The issue Im having is that the div with the id 'react' is not filling the entire body of the html page. Therefore any content I have inside of my application div overflows outside of the 'react' div.

This code pen illustrates my problem: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xGNejM

You can see at the bottom of the page that the lime background applied to the html tag is bleeding through. It is as if the body tag is not filling the whole screen. I thought setting height to 100% on html and body would handle this, but apparently not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try an implicit measurement on the body:

`body { height: 100vh; width: 100vw; }`

[**`vh` and `vw` `viewport height` and `viewport width`**](http://demosthenes.info/blog/660/Using-vw-and-vh-Measurements-In-Modern-Site-Design) are like `ems` on steroids.

**UPDATE**

http://arcx.s3.amazonaws.com/test.html

So according to what I've gathered, you need the content to be displayed from the `#react > #app` and the `#react > #app` itself must expand according to it's content `#child`. I did a couple of things:

- got rid of all the `position: relative`
- replaced the `height: 100%` with `height: 100vh`
- left no dimensions on `html,body` and added `position: fixed`
- added a `footer#foot` at the bottom with `position:relative` so there's padding at the bottom to prevent the content `#child` from being cutoff from the display.
- as suggested by @m1crdy I added `overflow: scroll` (I chose `scroll` over `auto` I don't like jumping scrollbars) to the `#child` but I didn't need to apply `overflow: hidden` to anything since I made the other components "static".

The content is editable, so type and hit enter key 100,000 times and it'll still expand without cutoffs or text jumping over borders. When you inject content inside, you might need a `<br`> or `\n` at the end for good measure.

Comment: When you apply 100% to that div#react, you are referencing it's parent. So it's 100% of what exactly? 100% of the body, right? So what is 100% of 100%?   By using an implicit measurement on the body you can base your 100% with more solid base. 1vh = 1% of the real height of your screen (viewport), 1vw = 1% of your screen's width.

Comment: if 1vw or 1vh = 1% then what make sense for the browser to pick out the difference.?

Comment: There's a link to an article that'll explain it better than I would. Click the bolded words.

Comment: i think this link appears after your answer have been updated

Comment: Actually it was there from the start, I just made it bolder because it didn't look obvious as a link.

Comment: Did you try this on the codepen link I provided? Because I did and it did not make any difference.

Comment: The update's here: http://arcx.s3.amazonaws.com/test.html you can edit the content, enter as many enter(carriage returns or equivalent to `<br>`) as you want, it'll just expand within  `#react > #app`

Comment: This looks good and I appreciate your help, but I still see one problem. Why does the fixed navbar get rendered on top of the vertical scroll bar?

Comment: The `#nav` is a sibling of `#child`, the scrollbar only applies to `#child`. Try placing the `#nav` inside the `#child` or put `overflow: scroll or auto` on `#app` if you want `#nav` to share the scrollbar. You can also take the `position: fixed` off of the `html,body` if you want an extra set of scrollbars. I think it looks messy, but it may be what you need. If your satisfied with the answer please accept it. I'll be happy to help you if need some more info, although I think you should be ok.

Answer (score 1):

100% height on html and body is filling the whole screen on startup, but not if the content is longer. Set your outer divs to `overflow:hidden` and your inner div to `overflow: auto`.

I have modified your [fiddle](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RPmmPG).

Comment: This solution is cutting off content in the "child" div. If you look closely the child div should contain three child <p> tags. In your solution the final <p> tag is not shown.